# Can I guarantee the render order of an array of React components?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an array of react components I'm trying to render in a specific order. Something like this:

```
render: function() {
  var items = stock.map(function(item) {
    return <NewLI data={item} key={item.id}/>
  }
  return <ul>{items}</ul>
}
```

My problem is that React is not returning the li's in the order of the original array (the actual component is more complex than a single `li`, but it is properly wrapped in a `div`).

so if print the `id` keys of `items`, I get this:

```
items.forEach(function(a) { console.log(a.id) })
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
```

but my React render looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li...>2</li>
  <li...>3</li>
  <li...>4</li>
  <li...>1</li>
</ul>
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to guarantee the order?

Comment: I have this literal problem, it sometimes happens where ReactJS decides to jumble the order but I am not able to find the pattern of why and the array order looks unchanged.

Comment: is render asynchronous? that is where I will start(having the same exact problem :()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not expected behavior.  React always renders arrays in the order of the elements.

If there are items with conflicting `key` values, only the latest element will render, but that doesn't look like the case here, since all four of your elements are rendered.

Any chance that is a custom `.map()` function that returns an object, and not another array?  Objects will render in key-iteration order, which isn't necessarily guaranteed consistent across browsers.

Comment: It's definitely an array and not an object, and the keys are id's generated by Django. I'll move this to the bottom of my list of suspects. 

When I step through, it does look like React renders the elements properly, but then they are rearranged without React re-rendering. Very strange.